# How do I get the absolute path of a resource in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to get the full absolute path to a resource including the domain name in Rails 3.

Example: to get the full path to the home page I have tried:

```
url_for( :controller => 'home', :action => 'index' )
```

and

```
root_path
```

but both give me just: `/` but I want: `http://www.example.com/`

The answer should also work on my dev server and return: `http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `root_url`. The `_url` extension on the end gives the full URL, something like `http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tickets/2`.

Answer (score 28):

Ryan's answer is perfectly correct.

However, if you really needed to use `url_for` someday, just add `:only_path => false` to it's options and it'll make the url absolute for you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the resouce url (instead of only the root url). You have to use resoure_name_url(@resource_instance)

Example:

```
resource_url(@resource_instance)
```

Or if you have (for example) the users resource:

```
user_url(@user)
```